# error in docker exec in eclipse-mosquitto

Tags: eclipse, docker

eclipse-mosquitto installed them with Docker on Ubuntu.
I want to execute the "docker exec" commands but it gives the following error?
Can you help?

```
sudo docker ps
```

outPut:

```
CONTAINER ID: b416d716ffd6   IMAGE: eclipse-mosquitto     COMMAND: "/docker-entrypoint.…"   CREATED: 2 days ago   STATUS: Up 44 minutes   PORTS: 0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11883->1883/tcp   NAME: charming_bohr
```

command:

```
sudo docker exec -it b416d716ffd6 /bin/bash
```

OutPut:
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown

---

for: The total number of bytes received since the broker started.

```
sudo docker exec -it b416d716ffd6 $SYS/broker/bytes/received
```

OutPut:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "/broker/bytes/received": stat /broker/bytes/received: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Comment: Hello, for the first error it means that it can't find /bin/bash in the container, it's probably not installed. You could try using `sh` instead -> `sudo docker exec -it b416d716ffd6 sh`

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct problem.

1. eclipse mosquitto image does not include bash so you need to use a different shell, for instance sh

   `sudo docker exec -it b416d716ffd6 /bin/sh
2. `$SYS/broker/bytes/received` is a special *topic* managed automatically and internally by mosquitto, you can access it "from outside" without exec-ing anything into the running container, for instance you can use mosquitto sub (`sudo apt-get install -y mosquitto_clients`, if you do not already have it)

   `mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/broker/bytes/received'`

adding `-h` option if mosquitto is not on localhost, `-p` if it is not on the default port, `-d` if you want it more verbose and so on.

For reference, this need of an MQTT client is clearly explained in [mosquitto man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html):

> Broker Status Clients can find information about the broker by
> subscribing to topics in the $SYS hierarchy as follows. Topics marked
> as static are only sent once per client on subscription. All other
> topics are updated every sys_interval seconds. If sys_interval is 0,
> then updates are not sent.
>
> Note that if you are using a command line client to interact with the
> $SYS topics and your shell interprets $ as an environment variable,
> you need to place the topic in single quotes '$SYS/...' or to escape
> the dollar symbol: $SYS/... otherwise the $SYS will be treated as an
> environment variable.
>
> $SYS/broker/bytes/received The total number of bytes received since
> the broker started.